# NodeJs + ExpressJS: router level middleware not able to take the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am making REST calls to my server. Now when I design my codes to handle routes in application level its working without any problems. But when I handle it using router level middleware its not working,

```
     var https = require("https");
        var express = require('express');
        var app = express();
        var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
        var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
        var path         = require('path');

        var routes = require('./server');  //require server directory

        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
        app.use(cookieParser());
        app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
        app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));
        });
        app.listen(3000);
        module.exports = app;
```

**This is my server directory where I have a file index.js**
And when I try to handle the request here using router its not taking the request. I am able to require the page to my app.js but just the router thing is not working.

```
    var https = require("https");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var gh = require('parse-github-url'); // use to break the url user provides into various parts
var moment = require('moment'); // for Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in JavaScript.
var router = express.Router();
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var _ = require('underscore-node');

router.post('/click', function(req, res){
    console.log("ewewew");
 });


module.exports = router;
```

When I keep try to handle the request in my application app.js its working fine.
For Eg:

```
 // If I keep it here it in app.js its working fine.
       app.post('/click',function(){
            console.log("dwfe");
        })
```

Comment: you need to register the router to app.

Comment: do you mean var router = express.Router(); in app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the router with app as shown below

```
app.use('/',router);
```

Refer [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router)

`express.Router()` just creates another Router, a isolated middleware instance. It has to be added to `app` middleware stack for it to be actually invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to attach the router object to the app object:

```
app.use('/', router);
```

The first parameter is the base url.